Multiple recipients in email finisher TYPO3 10.4.12
I need to configure a form with multiple recipients in TYPO3, but only the first gets the email.
Since 10.0 it should be possible https://docs.typo3.org/c/typo3/cms-core/main/en-us/Changelog/10.0/Feature-80420-AllowMultipleRecipientsInEmailFinisher.html
A form which I've tested with TYPO3 12, does not work in Version 10
renderingOptions:
  submitButtonLabel: Absenden
type: Form
identifier: mini2-v12
label: mini2v-12
prototypeName: standard
finishers:
  -
    options:
      subject: 'hier steht der betreff'
      recipients:
        recipient-one@gmx.de: recipient1
        recipient-two@t-online.de: recipient2
      senderAddress: form2@mydomain.de
      senderName: form2
      addHtmlPart: false
      attachUploads: false
      translation:
        language: Standard
      title: '{checkbox-1}'
      useFluidEmail: true
    identifier: EmailToReceiver
renderables:
  -
    renderingOptions:
      previousButtonLabel: 'Previous Step'
      nextButtonLabel: 'Next Step'
    type: Page
    identifier: page-1
    label: Step
    renderables:
      -
        type: Checkbox
        identifier: checkbox-1
        label: Checkbox
        properties:
          fluidAdditionalAttributes:
            required: required
        validators:
          -
            identifier: NotEmpty
      -
        defaultValue: ''
        type: Text
        identifier: text-1
        label: Text

I dont' have critical setting in my setup for the form-framework.
Has somebody a working form with more than one recipient or is possibly a bug?
Thanks in advance for your help

Did you check that your senderAddress is valid and the related mail domain has as much anti-spam measures in place as possible? Your example indicates at GMX and T-Online which would mean two different mail recipients with different rules. Maybe T-Online is stricter here. You could try two different GMX addresses instead or similar.

Thanks for your suggestion.
gmx and t-online are not the only email-adresses I've tried. And same reusult, when I swaped the sequenz of the recipient addresses. Gmx and t-online work with TYPO3 12 - same Hoster -, so I think it might has something to do with smtp or sendmail. In v10 and 12 the default settings are in use, sendmail with /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i .

In the meanwhile, the $singeAdressOption had been dropped. Maybe dive in with debugging in this direction can help: https://review.typo3.org/c/Packages/TYPO3.CMS/+/60544/37/typo3/sysext/form/Classes/Domain/Finishers/EmailFinisher.php#215

if it cannot be solved technically, then you could create a kind of distributor mail address and distribute the recipients from there.
